# How to draw tooltip in iOS

Tags: ios, swift

I really like this UI element in Apple's Measure app. How would I go about drawing something that looks like that?

[image]

It shouldn't be an image because I would like it to scale according to the text intrinsic size.

Comment: [`UIMenuItem`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uimenuitem) might help?

Comment: @Sweeper I'm not sure it allows in-depth customization (settings a background color, height, and width plus changing font and tooltip size).

Comment: Another approach can be using [an extension of `UIView` that uses a bezier path for the arrow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64000426/12470155)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

3 options

1- [UIPopoverPresentationController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44040184/uipopoverpresentationcontroller-on-iphone-with-ios-10)

2- [UIMenuController](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-create-custom-menus-using-uimenucontroller)

3- Usual `UIView` and the arrow is drawn by [QuadCurve](https://medium.com/@louistur/animating-with-quadratic-curves-in-swift-b18a79670aaa)

Comment: I think the `UIPopoverController` has been deprecated

Comment: @Cesare yes , it's substitute https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipopovercontroller ` `UIPopoverPresentationController`

Comment: `UIPopoverPresentationController` doesn't work on iPhone in portrait mode (a view controller is presented modally in full screen).

Comment: @Cesare i used it many times and it works in iphone , it's a bit very old when it was only run on ipad

Comment: @Cesare it works if you implement the UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate method, ***adaptivePresentationStyle*** and return **.none**. [SO]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25319179/uipopoverpresentationcontroller-on-ios-8-iphone